# Detecting CTRL+V using AS3 in IE

Tags: flash, actionscript, detect, ctrl

I am not able to detect the keyboard event <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on a swf using AS3 in IE. It seems to trigger the default browser behavior, and I'm not able to do anything... Any workaround for this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with IE and all control key combinations, though the same code works fine in FF.  What happens is that IE swallows the modified key's down event, so I only get:

[KeyboardEvent type="keyDown" ... charCode=0 keyCode=17 ... ctrlKey=true ...]
[KeyboardEvent type="keyUp" ... charCode=99 keyCode=67 ... ctrlKey=true ...]
[KeyboardEvent type="keyUp" ... charCode=0 keyCode=17 ...ctrlKey=false ...]

Adding evilpenguin's code didn't change the behavior.  (I was planning to add some conditions to limit the preventDefault() to certain keys later.)

Comment: Our internal testing found this same bug on the Mac with Firefox and Safari.

Comment: OK.  There are several odd behaviors I've identified.  1) The key down event never happens for a key that's pressed while the control key is pressed.  2) If you hold down the control key and repeatedly press other keys without releasing the control key, eventually no further key events happen.  3) After you stop receiving key events, you'll never see the control key up event (or any other key up event) when you finally release it.

Comment: I wrote an example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915620/actionscript-3-get-clipboard-data-fp-11

Answer (score 2):

If it's a browser behavior you're stumbling on, you can write some JavaScript to prevent it. There's another related post, about capturing key events in JS and relaying them to flash. See my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683486/javascript-to-actionscript-keypress-passing-utility/684220#684220) and focus on the `preventDefault()` part. You should just take out what you don't need of the code and leave something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
}
```

Of course, you'll have to import the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Clipboard.generalClipboard`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=CopyAndPaste_2.html)?