# In Flex, how to use command-shortcuts in the browser?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, macos, safari

I tried catching the command key shortcuts using the keyDown event and checking for KeyboardEvent.ctrlKey, but the browser(Safari) seemed to have intercepted all those key events because the shortcuts I am trying to use coincides with the safari ones. Is there anyway to override this behavior?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683486/javascript-to-actionscript-keypress-passing-utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to mitigate the native browser handling of keystrokes directly from flash. You could create an [adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) app if thats even an option or check out that comment posted on your question to try doing it with javascript.