# AS3 - Keyboard Event Not working for certain Keys

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard, addeventlistener

So this is weird, I'm using the exact same Key class that Kongregate.com gives you when you do their "Shootorials." It works nicely for arrow keys, but not so much when you try to use WASD controls. I couldn't get it to recognize the keyCode, so I started typing trace(); statements in the keyPressed event handler.

It turns out that my arrow keys, and some of my other keys like 'D', and 'G' will trigger the event. However other keys don't work. 'A', 'S'.

Why is my class working for some keys and not other keys?

Source Code

package 
{

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class Key {

    private static var initialized:Boolean = false;
    private static var keysDown:Object = new Object();  // stores key codes of all keys pressed

    public static function initialize(stage:Stage) {
        if (!initialized) {
            // assign listeners for key presses and deactivation of the player
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, clearKeys);
            // mark initialization as true so redundant
            // calls do not reassign the event handlers
            initialized = true;
            trace("Initialized [Keys]");
        }
    }


    public static function isDown(keyCode:uint):Boolean 
    {
        return Boolean(keyCode in keysDown);
    }


    private static function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        trace("Keyboard Event Trigger");
        keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
    }


    private static function keyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (event.keyCode in keysDown) {
            delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
        }
    }


    private static function clearKeys(event:Event):void {
        // clear all keys in keysDown since the player cannot detect keys being pressed or released when not focused
        keysDown = new Object();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks like it should work.  How are you invoking your `Key` class?  To run it, I had Key extend Sprite and set it as the application file in Flash Builder...but from what you posted, it seems clear that you have some other class calling `Key.initialize(stage);`.

Comment: Yes sir, my document class is called 'Game'. in the Game constructor, it calls Key.initialize(stage);  Exactly as you said.

Comment: Then I have another class called 'Ship' this is the player controlled MovieClip. Ship has an enterFrame event listener and inside that handler, it says if(Key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT) || Key.isDown(68)){ this.x += xSpeed;} The class has similar 'if' statements for all directions as well. It works for the arrow keys, it also works for the 'D' key and the 'W' key. It does not work for 'A' or 'S' for whatever reason. I can't see any reason why I can move to the right with the 'D' key, but I can't move left with the 'A' key.

Comment: Is it possible there is some other code listening for those keys?  
Or are there other keys being pressed at the same time? (there's usually a limit on simultaneous key presses)

Answer (score 0):

Did have the same issue once. Mine was tied to the browser i was running. Some browsers seem to highjack some keyboard events and don't let them bubble down to flash player.

Checking for the same issue in other browsers might give you an entry point to solve your problem.

Comment: I think you might be on to something. Would you mind elaborating? I export my project as a .swf and just run it from there using Adobe Flash Player. Nothing else is open, so I wonder what could be hijacking my keys. I tried setting the focus to the stage, but that didn't even change anything. (Not sure if it was supposed to)

Comment: Firefox, from what i know, is particularly weird with it's keyboard focus, Chrome from what i know, should pass the events just fine. The most reliable that i found to handle the issue is to use the external interface and have javascript pass the key codes or keys of interest.
this has a example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683486/javascript-to-actionscript-keypress-passing-utility

edit: Also watch for not handling the same events twice.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not running my .swf in a browser. It's straight off my laptop.

Comment: got this from AS3 reference: 
"Also, if you are using the Test Movie command in Flash, the authoring interface may respond to certain keys instead of the event listeners attached to the child sprite."

Answer (score 0):

Akos said to check if the browser was hijacking keyboard events. After investigating, I learned that it was my flash player itself that was hijacking my keys. Here's how I fixed it.

1. Run the .swf in whatever flash Player you desire.
2. Click 'Control' in the window menu
3. Check 'Disable Keyboard shortcuts'

Easy fix. Thanks for your help.