# Actionscript 3 Get clipboard data (fp 11)

Tags: actionscript-3, security, clipboard, flash

I would like to get clipboard text in AS3 (flex, flashdevelop). I know I can't just monitor clipboard, because while most other environments can, flash application are evil and can guess when they see a password and to what account it actually belongs. That's why I listen to an MouseEvent.CLICK event, but looks like it changed recently and Flash still says "no, no!". That's why I addEventListener ( Event.Paste ) to a TextField, but looks like the TextField doesn't dispatch such an Event.

I tried many solutions over Internet but they just don't work, and documentation regarding clipboard is often outdated.

Do I miss something, or Adobe's logo color has it's root in socialism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After years, I stumbled upon my own question to answer it.

Pasting in Flash is one of [User Initiated Actions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_uia_requirements.html). It must be initiated by either right-clicking and choosing `Paste` from built-in context menu or pressing `CTRL+V` combination (on Windows), when an `InteractiveObject` (except `TextField`) is in focus.

If these requirements are met, `Event.PASTE` will be dispatched, and inside a listener you can access the `Clipboard.getData()` method.

Only one thing is left, and brought me here in search of the solution: how to make the `Paste` button disabled in custom context menu, when there's nothing in the clipboard? It seems there's only one solution - to periodically check the `Clipboard.generalClipboard.formats.length`.

```
package simpletests 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.FocusEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;
import flash.desktop.Clipboard;
import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class PasteTest extends Sprite
{
    private var cont:ContextMenu;

    public function PasteTest() 
    {
        cont = new ContextMenu ();
        cont.hideBuiltInItems ();
        cont.clipboardMenu = true;

        var timer:Timer = new Timer ( 100 );

        this.contextMenu = cont;        
        stage.focus = stage;

        timer.start ();

        timer.addEventListener ( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer );
        stage.addEventListener ( FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onFocusOut );
        stage.addEventListener (Event.PASTE, onPaste );
    }

    private function onTimer ( e:TimerEvent ):void
    {
        cont.clipboardItems.paste = Clipboard.generalClipboard.formats.length;
    }

    private function onPaste ( e:Event ):void
    {
        trace ( Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT) );
    }

    private function onFocusOut ( e:FocusEvent ):void
    {
        stage.focus = stage;
    }

}
}
```

If you want to clear your clipboard for testing purposes, you might find wrong solutions, like executing a command like this: `%windir%\System32\cmd /c "echo off | clip"`. It puts an empty string into the clipboard and doesn't disable the "Paste" option in context menus. Instead (in Windows) cut and paste a file. This will gray out the `Paste` option in context menus.

Answer (score 1):

What about the `flash.desktop.Clipboard` class. This should be your way to access the clipboard. The class is available since Flash Player 10. With the `Clipboard` class you can read data from and write data to the system's clipboard in several predefined formats. Check the [API documentation of Clipboard class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html) to get detailed information about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I'm unlucky finding any working example. The one in docs linked by you works only in AIR: ("Note: Because of security restrictions on accessing clipboard data, this example does not work in Flash Player. In Flash Player, you can only call the getData() method of the Clipboard object in a paste event handler."). The thing is, it looks like actually getting the right Paste event involves a lot of setup (Textfields don't dispatch PasteEvent, maybe TLF does?)

Comment: You're right. I've checked the documentation again and there is a note under the `Event.PASTE` constant doc of the `Event` class. The old `flash.text.TextField` class doesn't dispatch any of the text modification events. You have to use components based on the FTE (Flash Text Engine). So you should use `fl.text.TLFTextField` instead of old TextField class. [Here's the doc with the note.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#PASTE)

Comment: Well, I guess I need to check fl package license for free flexsdk then. Thanks for your help!